Gain in electron angular momentum in spontaneous decay
Suppose I have an atom with electronic configuration $1s^2 2s^2 2p^5 3s$ in an excited state. Now this would decay to the ground state $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6$. In doing so, the outer electron gains an orbital angular momentum of one unit. Where does this angular momentum of the electron come from?

Does the atom emit anything during this decay? Perhaps a particle with spin 1?

@ChemiCalChems Okay, but what about a transition from a 2s orbital to a 1s orbital where there is no change in angular momentum of the electron, but there is a change in energy? It must emit a photon which has some angular momentum, while the electron's angular momentum remains unchanged, right?

But isn't a transition from 2s to 1s necessarily a spin-flip transition? Or, alternatively, it's a two-photon transition. Either way, you should be able to conserve momentum.
